# onAuthStateChanged runs on every re-render

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am using firestore onAuthStateChanged function to get the current auth state when my app is first loaded or on page refresh.

I have wrapped onAuthStateChanged in useEffect and provided an empty dependency array so that the function inside useEffect is called when the component is first mounted but not on every re-render.

But what I notice is that onAuthStateChanged runs on every re-render.

Am I wrong in my understanding of useEffect or onAuthStateChanged??

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks

```
  useEffect(() => {
    projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log('Inside Auth Function');
      dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_IS_READY', payload: user });
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You need to pass something in dependency array, so that it only re-renders based on that.

Comment: empty dependency array means it will run once, on component mount. So it seems fit for your purpose. Is something causing the component with this useEffect to unmount/remount?

Comment: actually this useEffect is part of a Context Provider Component.. This component for sure re-renders but I don't see any case where it mounts/unmounts